# Why isn't the unit of rate constant for any reaction always per second?

Tags: equilibrium, units, rate-equation

It is formally agreed upon that $K_{eq}=\prod_{j}a_j^{\nu_j}$ where $\nu_j$ is stoichiometric coefficient of species $j$ (negative for reactants and positive for products). This equation results in equilibrium constant not having any units. Experimentally, of course $K_c$ and $K_p$ are measured (and are of practical application). But everyone agrees that equilibrium constant has no units. 
Similarly, why do we not formally define rate constant as
$$
\frac{d}{dt}a_P=k\ \prod_{j}a_j^{\alpha_j}
$$
where $\alpha_j$ is order of reaction relative to species $j$ and $a_P$ is the activity of the product. 
This would mean that $k$ always had the unit $\textrm{s}^{-1}$ and, depending on the approximations used, the "unit" of rate constant may depend (analogous to $K_c$ and $K_p$). Why do chemists differentiate between the constants when it comes to units? 
Another thing to remember would be that $K_{eq}=k_1/k_{-1}$, so it definitely makes sense that rate constants have same units so as to treat $K_{eq}$ as a ratio.

Comment: Rate equation hardly has to be in such simple form.

Comment: You ask a lot at once, and seem to confuse some things and the reader along the way. Units and dimensions are not the same thing. And one can, and might be particularly inclined and justified to, write a rate equation like you suggest, using activities instead of concentrations (or pressures). How "formal" this is I can't say.